# Visual Studio Code malfunction after PC Restart

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

A few days ago, Visual Studio Code in my PC for C/C++ was working perfectly. After a Update Restart, suddenly it gave me an error message at start saying:

[image: Error Message]

After doing a little bit research, I found some similar questions/problems on other websites, but following the given steps to solve the error didn't help.

I tried:

1. Removing C/C++ Extension
2. Deleting the folder /Users/name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.1.0
3. Re-installing the C/C++ Extension

and

1. Re installing MingW

References:

1. [Problem Description and Expected Solution 1](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/3610/493143363)
2. [Problem Description and Expected Solution 2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5032)

But the issue still isn't resolved.
Furthermore, Visual Studio Code takes forever to Fetch build tasks.
[image: Build Task]

Any kind of assistance is helpful.

Comment: Did you look to see if the file mentioned in the error message still exists?  And if you have two questions, please post them as two separate posts.

Comment: My guess would be an antivirus scanner is deleting the language server for you